# factors of a number

Tags: elementary-number-theory, discrete-mathematics

I have to find exact n(any number specified) factors of a number whose all product combined yield the number and largest of n factors is minimised. 
Eg: n=2 for number 12; 12= 6*2,12*1,4*3,we will take 4*3 as largest of n factors is minimised here.

Rephrased:

> Given $n$ and $M$, write $M$ as a product of $n$ numbers so as to
>   minimise the largest of them.

What can be the approach to solve this problem?

My approach:
break number in prime factors as 12=2*2*3,count each unique number and then distribute it among the n factors like for n=2; let the factors be a and b then as count of "2" is 2 I distribute it as one "2" to both a and b then the remaining 3 can be given to any of a and b but it will produce a=2*3 and b=3
which is wrong,can anyone provide better solution?

Comment: I dont quite understand your question. what do you mean by largest of $n$ factors?

Comment: it means that n factors are given as n1,n2..nn.such that n1<=n2<=...nn.

Comment: then nn is largest of n factors

Comment: I have just edited your question to rephrase it - I think I understand, but am not sure. You should try to rewrite your approach in a similar way, and provide a few more examples of your approach.

Comment: @Ethan Bolker  I believe the problem is to minimize the largest factor, not to maximize it.

Comment: ya i have edited it

Comment: @saulspatz Indeed. Thanks.

Comment: Was this question on some kind of contest or exam recently ? Seems to be frequent and I'm curious :P

Comment: ya it was on one of coding contest the most toughest thing was to figure it out